# Rails mailer PDF attachment broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In one of my mailers I have this method to send an e-mail with an attached pdf:

```
def send_offer(customer, ip)
    @customer = customer
    attachments['offer.pdf'] = {
      :encoding => 'base64',
      :content  => Base64.encode64(File.read(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'offer.pdf')))
    }
    mail(:to => "mail@example.com",
         :from => "mail@example.com",
         :body =>"this tag is important when do any attachment",
         :subject => "#{@customer[:name]} Offer")
end
```

The e-mails is send, but when I open it the attached PDF is broken. The file size is `670 bytes`.

The original PDF is `263 KB (269.485 byte)`

How can that be?

Comment: Happens only on windows..

Comment: Have you tried it without the encoding? ActionMailer encodes Base64 by default: `attachments['offer.pdf'] = File.read(...)`

Comment: Have tried all kinds of solutions it will just not work on windows. It really dose not matter that much, because it works fine on UNIX systems.

Comment: Gotcha. Last suggestion I have is to open that 670 byte file in a text editor and see if it's something like an error message, or more likely, a file descriptor like `#<File:0x007fc9840b37e0>`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997725/how-to-attach-xls-files-to-email-when-sending-from-rails-and-not-getting-the-at) helped me to solve it:

```
attachments[file_name] = File.open(file_location, 'rb'){|f| f.read}
```